# Correct way to instantiate class with optional attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I'm currently migrating an JavaScript module to TypeScript, and I'm encountering issues when strongly typing an object with optional attributes.

The example is simple:

I've got a method opening a modal. The method has a single parameter, which is a map of the different options for the modal, and are all optional.

As in JavaScript:

```
openConfirmDialog({text : "are you sure ?"});
openConfirmDialog({title : "Confirmation required", confirmAction : noop});
```

and so on.

Migrating to TypeScript, I declared a class representing all these different options:

```
class ConfirmDialogOptions {

    text : string;
    title : string;

    confirmAction : () => any;
    cancelAction  : () => any;

}
```

but when trying to instantiate this class as we used to in plain JavaScript:

```
let confirmOptions : ConfirmDialogOptions = { text : "are you sure ?" };
```

the compiler raises an error:

> Initialized type not assignable to variable type ConfirmDialogOptions

And I'm forced to force type casting using:

```
let a : ConfirmDialogOptions = {text: "lala"} as ConfirmDialogOptions;
```

This works, but well, it seems kind of like overheat, and globally makes me wonder what is the correct approach to instantiate a typed object which have many or all optional properties in TypeScript.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of class declare an interface with [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties):

```
interface ConfirmDialogOptions {

    text ?: string;
    title ?: string;

    confirmAction ?: () => any;
    cancelAction  ?: () => any;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to use is TypeScripts [interface feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), which you can apply to free floating objects:

```
interface ConfirmDialogOptions {
  text?: string;
  title?: string;
  confirmAction?: () => any;
  cancelAction?: () => any;
}
```

`class` doesn't do what you think it does... It's actually an [ES6 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that acts as sugar around vanilla JavaScript functions.

```
// ES6 Class
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
}

// Equivalent JS
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Person;
}());
```

Since you're defining a `class` TypeScript assumes you're intending for `ConfirmDialogOptions` to match instances from a `new ConfirmationDialogOptions(...)` call, which isn't type equivalent with a vanilla JavaScript object like `{ text: 'hello' }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making the parameters optional with a question mark

```
class ConfirmDialogOptions {    
   text ?: string;
   title ?: string;
   //
}
```

Or a better way to declare class variables is in the constructor

```
class ConfirmDialogOptions {    
    constructor(private text?:string, private title?: string) {  }\
    //
}
```

An other solution is to give the parameters a default value

```
class ConfirmDialogOptions {    
    constructor(private text:string="Default text", private title: string="Default title") {  }
    //
}
```